# why sbt is resolving sites I haven't configured?

Tags: scala, sbt

In build.sbt, the only sites that I have configured are twitter and my own repo ,but why sbt is resolving sites like googlecode.com:

```
[error] Server access Error: Operation timed out url=http://maven.twttr.com/com/xxx/yyy_2.9.1/0.0.1/yyy_2.9.1-0.0.1.pom
[error] Server access Error: Operation timed out url=http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/repo/com/xxx/yyy_2.9.1/0.0.1/yyy_2.9.1-0.0.1.pom
[error] Server access Error: Operation timed out url=http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/maven/com/xxx/yyy_2.9.1/0.0.1/yyy_2.9.1-0.0.1.pom
```

it takes a loooong time to timeout, any way to disable it(or make the timeout shorter)?

Thanks ;-)

Comment: transitive dependencies?

Comment: timeout shorter: add the host to the hosts file as 127.0.0.1 for example.

Comment: My guess is that you added resolvers in a global sbt config file.

Comment: @dk14 I know transitive dependencies about jars, but what does that mean when talking about resolvers? Thanks

Comment: Maybe pom's of your direct dependencies in maven are pointing to another repositories (for their own dependencies)

Comment: @dk14 oh, thanks, but is there any way to disable this? basically its searching for my owner jars from sites like googlecode.com or twttr.com, which obviously won't find anything, while the timeout takes just too long.